# How can I make only the content refresh, or change, when new parameters i added?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have a couple of pages where the user can add and remove stuff in order to update the results. i.e. in a "ShoppingList"-page where the user can add/remove drinks in order to see what ingredients they need.

Each of these drinks is stored in a cookie, with PHP, so the user have the ability to navigate and explore the site, and then return without having to add the drinks again...

When the user do this, adds/removes drinks, the entire page is reloaded.
Drinks are added to a cookie immediately, before any html and stuff, then refreshed once again in order to build the php.mysql.query based on the values now stored in the cookie.

I think this is a lot of unnecesary reloading and stuff. It should be something more like just refreshing the actual content that needs to change, and not reloading everything else - Lots of unnecesary mysql requests just to add/remove a drink from the shoppinglist. And this of course slows site down..

Whenever the page is loaded, I need to check the cookie in order to present the correct results. Then, when a user adds/removes a drink, I would like to do this in the background (update the cookie and update the result). Hopefylly this could speed up the user experience.

I have a site up'n'running here - as a "prototype" : http://barkeeper.thomaskile.me/?side=handleliste (norwegian site, but google translate sort of gives you an idea of what it says. just tested it..)

This same thing goes for all three pages on my site so far..

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this? Is it som sort of jquery.AJAX-thing? If so. WHere do I start any sort of ajax-thing. Not sure how that works in practice when the user doesn't do anything (on page load)...

Comment: You've answered your own question, now you'll need to read up on ajax

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by manipulating DOM.

Remove the element from one list and create it in another list.

Checkout jQuery - the javascript library.